# Laravel reroute subfolder .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I need to deploy a Laravel project to a domain sub-folder. I already have the files in the correct places, i.e., the project folder in the same level as the `public_html` folder, and I have copied the contents of the public folder to the `public_html` (well, I created a `symlink` to tell the truth).

I only have one problem:

If I go to `my-domain.com/proj-name`, I can see the home page without a problem.
But when I go to a project page `my-domain.com/proj-name/about` (for example), I get a `404 Not Found: The requested URL /proj-name/about was not found on this server.`

I think the solution is to edit the RewriteRule on .htaccess so that when I browse to `my-domain.com/proj-name/about`, it removes the `proj-name` as if it was trying to access `my-domain.com/about`.

How can I do this?

Here is my current **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/proj-name/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proj-name/$1 [L]
```

**Note:** The above should go in the `.htaccess` located at `public_html` and not at `public_html/proj_name`

Comment: I created that `.htaccess` at `public_html`, but it still isn't working. Inside the `public_html`, besides this 2-line `.htaccess`, I've got a symbolic link called `proj_name`, which leads to the Laravel project `public` folder.

Comment: Your symlink is correct. Did you change the `.htaccess` inside `public` to its original state?

Comment: The `.htaccess` inside the `public` folder is the one I posted in my question (the one that is generated upon the Laravel 5.2 project creation).

Comment: @user2094178 Please improve the answer by saying which lines of which file should be edited. It's a bit hard to understand where to change what right now. :S